# Не верно работает ширина браузера

Tags: javascript

Почему мне выдает половину ширины браузера

```
var screen = window.screen.width;
var browserW = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
console.log(screen, browserW);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это также относится и к window.innerWidth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Свойства clientWidth/Height для элемента document.documentElement – это как раз ширина/высота видимой области окна. window.innerWidth/innerHeight они выполняют ту же самую функцию.
window.screen.width - возвращение ширины монитора.